# Deauth attack without being able to contact the AP

Tags: man-in-the-middle, kali-linux

In my home pentest lab I though it would be interesting to try this scenario and see if it works:

I have 2 computers and 1 AP, computer A is authenticated to the access point with WPA2 and computer B wants to run a MiTM attack on computer A by making it connect to a fake network. But, computer Bs antenna is not as powerful as computer As so in result computer B can only contact computer A and not the AP thus making a deauth attack though the usual tools useless.

My question is this: Is there a way/utility to deauth a computer without being able to get a frame from the AP?

Comment: A DeAuth IS sending packets to the computer and not the AP, but you need to know about the AP in order to impersonate it.

Comment: @KnightOfNi Any existing tools to manually feed the AP details without having to write my own script for that? Aireplay and most others I try wait for a frame from the AP, which obviously never comes since its out of range.

Comment: You can use Colasoft's Packet Builder, if you know what a DeAuth packet looks like. If not, I suppose you could intercept one with Wireshark and dissect it a bit from there

Comment: @KnightOfNi Ah ill try building a deauth packet with that. If you want post these comments as an answer, ill accept it.

Comment: I'd rather not, as I suspect there's an easier way out there somewhere. Thanks for the offer, though.

Comment: This will not directly help, and you would have already had thought about it, but if there is no other way, then get a USB WiFi card with an antenna strong enough to do the job. I know this answer isn't at all helpful. I am just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the **BSSID** information from the AP to run the aireplay command. Since you said that you are looking for a tool that would let you provide the AP information manually, the command would be like this:

```
aireplay-ng -0 1 -a <AP BSSID> -c <COMPUTER A> interface
```

And to get the AP BSSID you could use the **airodump-ng**, and look at the AP computer A is connected at. (in this case, airodump would get the BSSID based on the computer that is connected to it)